Diode SPICE model for the HSMS-2860 in CST schematic
Trying to create diode in CST schematic but getting this error.
Use same values and import it in CST as .lib file (notepad file names as .lib). Transmission lines used for impedance matching.
Following values taken from Avago HSMS-286x Series Surface Mount Microwave Schottky Detector Diodes datasheet (from Mouser):
.MODEL HSMS2860 D 
+BV = 7 
+CJO = 0.18E-12 
+EG = 0.69 
+IBV = 1E-5 
+IS = 5E-8 
+N = 1.08 
+RS = 6.0 
+VJ = 0.65 
+XTI = 2 
+M = 0.5






Image source: Avago HSMS-286x Series Surface Mount Microwave Schottky Detector Diodes datasheet (from Mouser)

Did you specify a dc bias point for the diode in your simulation?

Do you have access to ADS? At one time Keysight and the part of Broadcom that makes this device were all part of Agilent (and before that, HP), and they are still likely to provide ADS models for their devices. ADS is also quite good at modeling this kind of circuit.

Also, this diode has been obsolete for over 10 years link (Before Avago and Broadcom merged) --- that may make it harder to get a model from Broadcom.

@ThePhoton ADS installation will be done today.

@ThePhoton ADS license not available at the moment. So I have to do it in CST schematic. Any diode can be used to work as a RF switch and it should do switching as open and short circuit (ON/OFF state). In other words the reflection coefficient of antenna with this diode should switch between 1 and -1.


A real diode (and an accurate simulator model) has junction capacitance, so can't block RF at high enough frequencies. 2. Whether the reflection is 1 or -1, no power is being transmitted from your antenna. If you want to transmit you need $|\Gamma|<1$.

